# Angular - trigger unsavedChanges directive when user clicks on a non-submit button

Tags: angularjs

How do I trigger the angular-unsavedChanges directive to check to see if a form is dirty when a user clicks on a button in a form that is not a submit button?  I want a message to pop-up if the user clicks on a button that would navigate them to a different page, if changes have been made to the current form.  It seems to work on a refresh and a link to a different page, but not a button that will be loading a different template.  TIA.

Comment: which angular-unsavedChanges directive do you use ? There are at least 2 : facultymatt/ and umbrella-web/. The latter seems to be designed to be accessed programmatically, so I'm guessing the former ?

Comment: Sorry, I didn't know there was more than one.  Yes, I'm using the facultymatt.

Comment: Thanks for the info. One more question : how do you navigate with the button ? Does it call $location ? Also, is there a reason why you would use a real button to navigate and not a link skinned as one ?

Comment: This is a SPA.  The two buttons in question just load a different template on the ng-click event.  I tried to use a link skinned as a button, but it seems that by using a ng-click instead of a href, the unsavedChanges directive doesn't get triggered.  No, I'm not using $location.

Answer (score 0):

Without sample code, I can't be sure, but I think that since the directive you are using specifically binds to the `$locationChangeStart` event, you could try the following :
configure your $routeProvider to monitor url changes ( I suppose it is already what you are doing with your SPA, but correct me if I'm wrong)

```
$routeProvider
    .when('/otherPage', {
        templateUrl: 'partials/myOtherPage.html',
        controller: 'OtherCtrl',
      })
```

Use you the ng-click on your button to call the $location service (don't forget to pass it to your controller)

```
$scope.navigateToOtherPage = function() {
    $location.path('/otherPage');
}
```

Since $`location` fires the `$locationChangeStart` event right before changing the url, your directive should be able to capture it and proceed with its expected behaviour.